# Publish a story on Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm very new to Facebook Open Graph. What I want to do is simply when a user opens a webpage, it will send a story to his/her timeline. I have created an "Eat a Meal" action on Open Graph. When I click Get code, I get something like this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/project:eat?
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&
method=POST&
meal=http%3A%2F%2Fsamples.ogp.me%2F325653997592127
```

When I click on this code, I am redirected to another page. I get an Access Token there and then when I click submit I get something like this :

```
{
  "id": "274655529384281"
}
```

When I click the id, I get this :

```
{
  "id": "274555552716206", 
  "from": {
    "id": "274673726099999", 
    "name": "Jason McJason"
  }, 
  "start_time": "2014-07-16T14:23:26+0000", 
  "end_time": "2014-07-16T14:23:26+0000", 
  "publish_time": "2014-07-16T14:23:26+0000", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Project", 
    "namespace": "project", 
    "id": "325123427594834"
  }, 
  "data": {
    "meal": {
      "id": "539535656565608", 
      "url": "http://samples.ogp.me/325625656562127", 
      "type": "project:meal", 
      "title": "Sample Meal"
    }
  }, 
  "type": "project:eat", 
  "likes": {
    "count": 0, 
    "can_like": true, 
    "user_likes": false
  }, 
  "comments": {
    "count": 0, 
    "can_comment": true, 
    "comment_order": "chronological"
  }
}
```

But I don't know what to do with all of this data. I just have a simple HTML page. Where should I put these data? I'm a little lost and Facebook's documentation didn't help much. I'd appreciate if you tell me what to do with these. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to integrate Facebook JS SDK on your web page.

Read up through this documentation- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0

The very last example creates a post.